# Vue-CLI webpack-simple template - How to run build

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a Vue.js app that runs perfectly fine with `npm run dev`, but when doing `npm run build` and opening the index.html, there will be no activity, only a blank page.

The directory in the html is `dist/build.js`, which is loaded correctly.

This is the webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  publicPath: 'dist/',
  filename: 'build.js'
},
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader'
    ],
  },      {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
      }
      // other vue-loader options go here
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|png)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
  }
]
},
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  },
  extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
  }
}),
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  sourceMap: true,
  compress: {
    warnings: false
  }
}),
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  minimize: true
})
])
}
```

These are the dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^4.10.1",
"vue": "^2.5.11",
"vue-router": "^3.0.1",
"vuefire": "^1.4.5",
"vuex": "^3.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
  "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
  "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
  "webpack": "^3.6.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
}
```

The dist folder and index.html are in the same directory. The index.html shows no content or errors in log.

Comment: How are you _"opening the index.html"_?

Comment: @Phil I'm opening it as an ordinary static html file (just double clicking it). The source in the html for the build is `dist/build.js` (It's linked but nothing happens)

Comment: I resolved this issue by editing the firebase.json file and setting property "public" to a dot: "."  (top folder).This is because Vue and Firebase use a different default folder structure and firebase looks in the wrong place.. Alternatively, you can edit both firebase.json and webpack.config.json to make them both use some common sub folder like public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're opening the `index.html` file directly, eg

```
file:///home/you/some-project-folder/index.html
```

The webpack-simple template assumes you'll be serving your app via an HTTP server with the app at the document root (ie `/`).

You can see this in the `index.html`...

```
<script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
```

Note the `/` prefix.

The idea is that you upload `index.html` and the `dist` folder to some hosting provider's server.

Now, you could edit this path to be `dist/build.js` and it may work but paths to assets will probably be wrong and any AJAX requests may not work due to browser limitations on resources loaded via `file:///`

Comment: while this didn't directly solve a similar issue, it got me thinking about the problem correctly..  +1